# Expo - React Native GeoFence with API Data

Tags: api, react-native, geolocation, expo

I am trying to work on a simple proof of concept for geofencing around certain latitude and longitudes

Structure: - location service is turned on (no need background updates for now just initial location) - user location is determined - looks at data of locations in json file and finds the ones in close proximity @10km (refer to URL for API)

EXPO has recently updated the SDK to manage this, but with looking through multiple searches nothing really comes up with managing a simple task of placing static location to a database and then runs the proximity radius.

Using a basic setup for the concept but not sure next steps... Below is the setup that I have for now and would like some direction on where the GeoFence calls begins

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
    import { Constants, MapView, Location, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super ()
    this.state = {
      dataSource: []
    }
  }

  state = {
    mapRegion: null,
    hasLocationPermissions: false,
    locationResult: null
  };

  _handleMapRegionChange = mapRegion => {
    console.log(mapRegion);
    this.setState({ mapRegion });
  };

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
   let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
   if (status !== 'granted') {
     this.setState({
       locationResult: 'Permission to access location was denied',
     });
   } else {
     this.setState({ hasLocationPermissions: true });
   }

   let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
   this.setState({ locationResult: JSON.stringify(location) });

   // Center the map on the location we just fetched.
    this.setState({mapRegion: { latitude: location.coords.latitude, longitude: location.coords.longitude, latitudeDelta: 0.0922, longitudeDelta: 0.0421 }});
  };

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.code}  
        <Text>{item.name} 
        <Text>{item.lat} 
        <Text>{item.lon} 
        </Text>
        </Text>
        </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )}

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
    //const url = 'https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccLAsEcOSq?indent=1'
    const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tdreyno/4278655/raw/7b0762c09b519f40397e4c3e100b097d861f5588/airports.json'
    fetch(url)
    .then((repsonse) => repsonse.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Pan, zoom, and tap on the map!
        </Text>

        {
          this.state.locationResult === null ?
          <Text>Finding your current location...</Text> :
          this.state.hasLocationPermissions === false ?
            <Text>Location permissions are not granted.</Text> :
            this.state.mapRegion === null ?
            <Text>Map region doesn't exist.</Text> :
            <MapView
              style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 200 }}
              region={this.state.mapRegion}
              onRegionChange={this._handleMapRegionChange}
            />
        }

        <Text>
          Location: {this.state.locationResult}
        </Text>

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          //={[{ key: 'a'}, { key: 'b'}]}
          //renderItem={({item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          />
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

This is only proof of concept and just need some directions which will help me move on. Links and Tutorials anything will help

Thanks (still learning)

Comment: Did you discover what's wrong? I'm basically with the same issue and there's no examples online :/

Comment: @soalrib - no success at the moment - will be looking at geofire for an alternative

Comment: I'm trying with geolib, check that too